# Hibernate - ManyToOne - Save - org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:

Tags: hibernate, jpa

While I try to save top level entity (using JPA), do I need to get the ManyToOne mapped entity freshly from database and set it or cannot I just set Id (of manyToOne mapped entity and save top level entity?
When do not get fresh entity it throws: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException:

Table structures we are using:

```
DEPARTMENT(DEPARTMENT_ID BIGINT, NAME VARCHAR(128))

EMPLOYEE(EMPLOYEE_ID BIGINT, NAME VARCHAR(128), DEPARTMENT_ID BIGINT)

Entities:
class Department
{
   @Id
   Long departmentId;
   String name;
   @Version
   Long versionNumber;
}

class Employee
{
   @Id
   Long employeeId;
   String name;
   @ManyToOne
   Department department;
   @Version
   Long versionNumber
}
```

(both classes have setter and getter methods for all fields and default constructor, constructor which takes primary key as argument)
Now if I want to save Employee with departmentId (say 100), do I need to get the Department record first and then set it in employee?

Cannot I create instance of Department directly (by setting primary key(departmentId)) and set Department instance in Employee and save Employee?
When I do this it is throwing org.hibernate.TransientObjectException.

Any suggestions on best practice to be followed for this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you ChssPly76 and Wysawyg.

One of the solution could be:
We will update Employee POJO as below

```
ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@**JoinColumn**(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "DEPARTMENT_ID", **insertable=false, updatable=false**)
private Department department;

@Column(name = "department_id")
private Long departmentId;
```

(both department and departmentId will have setter and getter methods)

and Now here (please see that both department and departmentId mapped to same column (DEPARTMENT_ID)
we use **department** only for fetching Department details
and departmentId to insert or update **Employee**

But I am worried if it is a better approach.

Comment: I do not know who has downvoted this? Can they justify please?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to associate your `Employee` instance with **new** `Department instance, you can set [an appropriate cascading behavior](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association-cascade) and let Hibernate take care  of the whole thing:

```
class Employee {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  Department department;
}
```

Note that you do **NOT** want to use `CascadeType.ALL` because deleting an employee should not delete a department.

If, OTOH, you want to associate your `Employee` instance with **existing** `Department instance, your best approach is indeed to load it. You can use [session.load()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-loading) method for that purpose which **will not hit the database**.

An alternative solution is to use [session.merge()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached) on `Employee` which (with cascading as specified above) will propagate to `Department`. This can have side effects, though.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I missed in typing that it was @ManyToOne instead of vice versa. Yes, Cascade.All would be bad!

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is little different. I do not want to hit the database at all.

Comment: As I said above, use `session.load()` - it will not hit the database at all up until you flush / commit.

Comment: @ChssPly76 can you look into my question as well.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284974/manytoone-save-parent-record-alone-spring-jpa.Whether Kumar D answer is the only way to go forward with this issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the parent without saving each of the children, you need to map it something like (I can't remember the exact syntax)

```
@ManyToOne(CascadeType = Cascade.All)
Department department;
```

EDIT: I made the mistake of seeing it as parent-to-child instead of child-to-parent. Follow ChssPly76's example.