# Cascade.ALL works, but not CascadeType.PERSIST not for saving new entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entites:

```
Channel

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "campaign_business_id")
private CampaignBusiness campaignBusiness;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id")
private Campaign campaign;


Campaign

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
private Event event;

CampaignBusiness 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id")
private Campaign campaign;
```

I would like to use only **Cascade.PERSIST** - since I want the records to be updated and not deleted upon casacde.

However, when I write *instead* of **Cascade.ALL**, **Cascade.PERSIST** and use the following code:

```
Event event = new Event();
Campaign campaign = new Campaign();
campaign.setEvent(event);
CampaignBusiness campaignBusiness = new CampaignBusiness();
campaignBusiness.setCampaign(campaign);
Channel channel = new Channel();
channel.setCampaign(campaign);
channel.setCampaignBusiness(campaignBusiness);
channelDAO.save(channel);
```

I get an exception

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

Comment: why do you have `event` in `Channel` when it is already in `Campaign`?

Comment: My mistake - I don't have it. I removed it from there

Comment: What does CampaignBusiness look like? It seems to also have campaign?

Comment: @Charlie yes it has the campaign but no cascade on it

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900788/hibernate-manytoone-save-org-hibernate-transientobjectexception

Comment: @Nandkumar I didn't like the answer there. It looks to more like a hack than a real answer

Comment: can you give cascade type `CascadeType.MERGE` with persist and check if it works ?

Comment: @Nandkumar I checked it with CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH and it also didn't work. Only when I checked it with ALL it worked

Comment: `Campaign` in channel and CampaignBusiness are different?

Comment: No. they are the same. CampaignBusiness is a many to many table - each business can have many campaigns and every campaign can have many businesses